# Skipping text file lines on reiteration of loop

Tags: c++, arrays, file, loops, multidimensional-array

I have a loop which successfully reads the first 9 lines of a text file into an array and makes appropriate use of it. On each additional pass I would like to skip 9 lines of the text file and overwrite the array from there. (each section of 9 lines has the same type of information)

The problem is that I can't seem to get it to skip. I have a variable which increments by 9 each time there is a pass, up to the number of 9 part sections, which itself would be from a variable generated by measuring the lines of the text file.

I thought the simplest approach would be to increase the variable in this loop by the current value  of lines I want to skip, but that either didn't do anything, crashed the program, or made the output jumbled, depending on how I approached it.

This is the area of text that is currently passing information from the text file into a 2D array (and removing white space)

```
for (int x = (0); x < BOARD_SIZE + 1; ++x)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < BOARD_SIZE; ++y)
    {
        // Initializing as Z because that's not a possible input from file.
        // If it appears something is wrong.
        char point = 'Z';

        if (!file.get(point))
            cout << "There seems to be a problem with the file." << x << "," << y << endl;

        if (isblank(point))
        {
            // Without this, it will spit out spaces every other character of the array
            --y; 
        }
        else
        {
            chessBoards[x][y] = point;
        }
    }
}
```

As it is written right now, the program works, and produces a number of tables equal to the number of tables in the file, but prints onto the screen an exact copy of the first table for each pass.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `fgetpos` to save the point in the file where the first 9 lines end.

Then, on the next loop, you can use `fsetpos` to retreive the position of the text file.

Here is how you do it:

- First declare the variable to store your position. The type used is `fpos_t`
- Then at the point where the loop reaches the end of the 9th line, use `getpos` to save the position of the file.
- You can retrieve the position using `fsetpos` and continue from where the previous loop has left off

  fpos_t pos;

  fgetpos(fp, &pos);   // save the position

  fsetpos(fp, &pos);   // now restore the position to where we saved

Comment: That definitely sounds like a good approach. Unfortunately, the text file is chosen by the user and when I apparently have to open the file using a different approach which gives me errors when I am not using constants. Unless that's wrong? Very well answered though.

Comment: Looks like it also has to be a char.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did to make it work:

Until the file is closed it won't lose place, so instead of closing it at the end of the loop and then trying to reopen, I had this near the top of the loop:

```
if (!file.is_open())
{
    file.open(games);
}
```

This simply checks if the file is open. If it is not open, it will open it. This way the file will open on the first run and won't try to reopen. The file can then be closed after the loop ends.

Certainly easier than changing the way the files open or going through the process of storing variables to keep track of things.

Answer (score 0):

I called this going into the rabbit hole problem.

You have to simulate or write a `if then else` loop that does not utilize the existing reiteration `++x`.

Another way is to use a variable that other than `x` and `y` as well as `z` which use your mapped coordinate system.  For example, label you reiteration loop as `reitLoopX` and `reitLoopY`.  However, the way you stated the problem your complier has naming convention locks.